# "Paste into shape" in Illustrator 2020

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow

At the bottom of the toolbar in Illustrator there used to be an option to paste inside a shape:

[image]

It's a really convenient that helps you not have to make a clipping mask if you don't have to, and closer in use to the user-friendly way of placing an element inside another of InDesign.

**But I cannot find this great feature anymore in Illustrator 2020. Where is it?**

Answer (score 4):

It is there, it is just dimmed because you have nothing selected on your artboard. It is called "Draw Inside" mode and you can toggle the different drawing modes with the keyboard shortcut Shift+D. If you select something on your artboard for it to "Draw Inside" then it will be available for you.

It  is true that it helps you not have to make a clipping mask manually, but it does create a Clipping Group the same as if you went to Object> Clipping Mask> Make.

Edit-
Here are the screenshots you requested:

NOT SELECTED

[image]

SELECTED

[image]

Comment: Could you put a screenshot in your answer? Thanks